# Uploading picture in ASP.net core stays NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to pass the filepath into my ProfileViewModel but it seems to stay Null even thought the other values are filled.

I have tried debugging it but cant seem to find where its going wrong.

My view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <input asp-for="Photo" type="file"/><br />

        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my controller

```
        public IActionResult profile()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment he;
        public ProfileController(IHostingEnvironment e)
        {
            he = e;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfileViewModel profile)
        {
            string ID = Request.Cookies["UserID"];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var Photo = profile.Photo;
                var FileName = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath, Path.GetFileName(Photo.FileName));
                if (logicprofile.logicEditProfile(profile.BIO, profile.Sex, profile.Preffered, FileName, Convert.ToInt32(ID)) == true)
                {
                    profile.Photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create));
                    ViewBag.Message = "Profile Updated";
                    return View("profile", profile);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Something went wrong";
                    return View("profile", profile);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View("profile", profile);
            }


        }
```

ViewModel

```
[DisplayName("A picture of you!")]
public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
```

I expect my pictures to be saved in a folder and the path to a database so I can use them as profile pictures.

Comment: Is it possible that the form is missing `multipart/form-data` which means that any files selected won't be uploaded?

Comment: @Steve this could be totally possible have never uploaded files to asp.net core yet. Other values are being uploaded like name and sex.

Comment: @Ruben check my answer if it help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use enctype in form for passing file type data.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: after changing `@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post))` to `@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` I still stays null

Comment: in your controller method also write [HttpPost] above your method.

For Example :

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfileViewModel profile){}

Comment: It identifies that your method is a Post method

Comment: I have updated the code to what I have now and included my view model. Still it seems to be not working